# How to properly use context variables in OrientDB ETL configuration file?

Tags: orientdb

### Summary

Trying to learn about OrientDB ETL configuration json file.

Assuming a CSV file where:

- each row is a single vertex
- a 'class' column gives the intended class of the vertex
- there are multiple classes for the vertices (Foo, Bar, Baz)

How do I set the class of the vertex to be the value of the 'class' column?

---

### Efforts to Troubleshoot

I have spent a LOT of time in the OrientDB ETL documentation trying to solve this.  I have tried many different combinations of `let` and `block` and `code` components.  I have tried variable names like `className` and `$className` and `${classname}`.

**Current Results**:

- The `code` component is able to correctly print the value of `className', so I know that it is being set correctly.
- The `vertex` component isn't referencing the variable correctly, and consequently sets the class of each vertex to `null`.

#### Context

I have a freshly created database (`PLOCAL GRAPH`) on localhost called 'deleteme'.

I have an vertex CSV file (nodes.csv) that looks like this:

```
id,name,class
1,Jack,Foo
2,Jill,Bar
3,Gephri,Baz
```

And an ETL configuration file (test.json) that looks like this:

```json
{
  "config": {
    "log": "DEBUG"
  },
  "source": {"file": {"path": "nodes.csv"}},
  "extractor": {"csv": {}},
  "transformers": [
    {"block": {"let": {"name": "$className",
                       "value": "$input.class"}}},
    {"code": {"language": "Javascript",
              "code": "print(className + '\\n'); input;"}},
    {"vertex": {"class": "$className"}}
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "remote:localhost:2424/deleteme",
      "dbUser": "admin",
      "dbPassword": "admin",
      "dbType": "graph",
      "tx": false,
      "wal": false,
      "batchCommit": 1000,
      "classes": [
        {"name": "Foo", "extends": "V"},
        {"name": "Bar", "extends": "V"},
        {"name": "Baz", "extends": "V"}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And when I run the ETL job, I have output that looks like this:

```
aj@host:~/bin/orientdb-community-2.1.13/bin$ ./oetl.sh test.json
OrientDB etl v.2.1.13 (build 2.1.x@r9bc1a54a4a62c4de555fc5360357f446f8d2bc84; 2016-03-14 17:00:05+0000) www.orientdb.com
BEGIN ETL PROCESSOR
[file] INFO Reading from file nodes.csv with encoding UTF-8
[orientdb] DEBUG - OrientDBLoader: created vertex class 'Foo' extends 'V'
[orientdb] DEBUG orientdb: found 0 vertices in class 'null'
+ extracted 0 rows (0 rows/sec) - 0 rows -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertices/sec) Total time: 1001ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
[orientdb] DEBUG - OrientDBLoader: created vertex class 'Bar' extends 'V'
[orientdb] DEBUG orientdb: found 0 vertices in class 'null'
[orientdb] DEBUG - OrientDBLoader: created vertex class 'Baz' extends 'V'
[orientdb] DEBUG orientdb: found 0 vertices in class 'null'
[csv] DEBUG document={id:1,class:Foo,name:Jack}
[1:block] DEBUG Transformer input: {id:1,class:Foo,name:Jack}
[1:block] DEBUG Transformer output: {id:1,class:Foo,name:Jack}
[1:code] DEBUG Transformer input: {id:1,class:Foo,name:Jack}
Foo
[1:code] DEBUG executed code=OCommandExecutorScript [text=print(className); input;], result={id:1,class:Foo,name:Jack}
[1:code] DEBUG Transformer output: {id:1,class:Foo,name:Jack}
[1:vertex] DEBUG Transformer input: {id:1,class:Foo,name:Jack}
[1:vertex] DEBUG Transformer output: v(null)[#3:0]
[csv] DEBUG document={id:2,class:Bar,name:Jill}
[2:block] DEBUG Transformer input: {id:2,class:Bar,name:Jill}
[2:block] DEBUG Transformer output: {id:2,class:Bar,name:Jill}
[2:code] DEBUG Transformer input: {id:2,class:Bar,name:Jill}
Bar
[2:code] DEBUG executed code=OCommandExecutorScript [text=print(className); input;], result={id:2,class:Bar,name:Jill}
[2:code] DEBUG Transformer output: {id:2,class:Bar,name:Jill}
[2:vertex] DEBUG Transformer input: {id:2,class:Bar,name:Jill}
[2:vertex] DEBUG Transformer output: v(null)[#3:1]
[csv] DEBUG document={id:3,class:Baz,name:Gephri}
[3:block] DEBUG Transformer input: {id:3,class:Baz,name:Gephri}
[3:block] DEBUG Transformer output: {id:3,class:Baz,name:Gephri}
[3:code] DEBUG Transformer input: {id:3,class:Baz,name:Gephri}
Baz
[3:code] DEBUG executed code=OCommandExecutorScript [text=print(className); input;], result={id:3,class:Baz,name:Gephri}
[3:code] DEBUG Transformer output: {id:3,class:Baz,name:Gephri}
[3:vertex] DEBUG Transformer input: {id:3,class:Baz,name:Gephri}
[3:vertex] DEBUG Transformer output: v(null)[#3:2]
END ETL PROCESSOR
+ extracted 3 rows (4 rows/sec) - 3 rows -> loaded 3 vertices (4 vertices/sec) Total time: 1684ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
```

Oh, and what does `DEBUG orientdb: found 0 vertices in class 'null'` mean?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I wrestled with this for awhile too, but the below setup worked for me.

Note that setting `@class` *before* the `vertex` transformer will initialize a Vertex with the proper class.

```
"transformers": [
    {"block": {"let": {"name": "$className",
                       "value": "$input.class"}}},
    {"code": {"language": "Javascript",
              "code": "print(className + '\\n'); input;"}},
    { "field": {
        "fieldName": "@class",
        "expression": "$className"
      }
    },
    {"vertex": {}}
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your result, you could use "ETL" to import data from csv into a CLASS named "Generic".
Through an JS function, "separateClass ()", create new classes taking the name from the property 'Class' imported from csv, and put vertices from class Generic to new classes.

[image]

File json:

```
    {
    "source": { "file": {"path": "data.csv"}},
    "extractor": { "row": {}},
  "begin": [
   { "let": { "name": "$className", "value": "Generic"} }
  ],
    "transformers": [
        {"csv": {
            "separator": ",",
            "nullValue": "NULL",
            "columnsOnFirstLine": true,
            "columns": [
                "id:Integer",
                "name:String",
                "class:String"
                ]
            }
        },

        {"vertex": {"class": "$className", "skipDuplicates": true}}
    ],
    "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "remote:localhost/test",
            "dbType": "graph"
        }
    }
}
```

After importing the data  from etl, in javascript creates the function

```
var g = orient.getGraphNoTx(); 
var queryResult= g.command("sql", "SELECT FROM Generic"); 

//example filed vertex: ID, NAME, CLASS 
if (!queryResult.length) {
print("Empty");
} else {
   //for each value create or insert in class
   for (var i = 0; i < queryResult.length; i++) {
     var className = queryResult[i].getProperty("class").toString();

     //chech is className is already created
     var countClass = g.command("sql","select from V where @class = '"+className+"'"); 

     if (!countClass.length) {
       g.command("sql","CREATE CLASS "+className+" extends V");  
       g.command("sql"," CREATE PROPERTY "+className+".id INTEGER");  
       g.command("sql"," CREATE PROPERTY "+className+".name STRING"); 
       g.commit();
     } 

      var id =  queryResult[i].getProperty("id").toString();
      var name = queryResult[i].getProperty("name").toString();
      g.command("sql","INSERT INTO "+className+ " (id, name) VALUES ("+id+",'"+name+"')"); 
      g.commit();
   }

  //remove class generic
  g.command("sql","truncate class Generic unsafe");
}
```

the result should be like the one shown in the picture.